# My "Worksheet_SelectionChange" code requires that I select each cell again before the pivot tables are updated

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

My "Worksheet_SelectionChange" code (to control pivot table fields with cell values) requires that I select each cell again before the pivot tables (on a separate sheet) are updated. Is there a way for me to have the pivot tables update as soon I enter a value into the linked cell? I'm having to run another code just to select all the cells one by one to update the pivot tables. Apologies if my code is not formatted properly. I'm new to VBA and Stackoverflow. I appreciate any advice.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim rngIndustry1 As Range
Dim rngIndustry2 As Range
Dim rngIndustry3 As Range
Dim rngIndustry4 As Range

Set rngIndustry1 = Me.Range("Industry1")
Set rngIndustry2 = Me.Range("Industry2")
Set rngIndustry3 = Me.Range("Industry3")
Set rngIndustry4 = Me.Range("Industry4")

' Industry 1
If Not Application.Intersect(Target, rngIndustry1) Is Nothing Then
        With Sheets("Pivots").PivotTables("pvtIndustry1").PivotFields("Industry")

        If Len(rngIndustry1.Value) > 0 Then .CurrentPage = rngIndustry1.Value
    End With '<this line changes
End If

' Industry 2
If Not Application.Intersect(Target, rngIndustry2) Is Nothing Then
    With Sheets("Pivots").PivotTables("pvtIndustry2").PivotFields("Industry")

        If Len(rngIndustry2.Value) > 0 Then .CurrentPage = rngIndustry2.Value
    End With
End If

' Industry 3
If Not Application.Intersect(Target, rngIndustry3) Is Nothing Then
    With Sheets("Pivots").PivotTables("pvtIndustry3").PivotFields("Industry")

        If Len(rngIndustry3.Value) > 0 Then .CurrentPage = rngIndustry3.Value
    End With
End If

' Industry 4
If Not Application.Intersect(Target, rngIndustry4) Is Nothing Then
    With Sheets("Pivots").PivotTables("pvtIndustry4").PivotFields("Industry")

        If Len(rngIndustry4.Value) > 0 Then .CurrentPage = rngIndustry4.Value
    End With
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: `SelectionChange` is invoked when the... selection is changed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `Worksheet_SelectionChange()` you can use `Worksheet_Change()` and use the `Intersect()` to check which cells are changed